# deploying ML model RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ScriptRunner.scriptThread'

Tags: heroku, deployment, jupyter, streamlit

```py
import streamlit as st
import pickle
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model


model = (open('gru.pkl','rb'))

def predict_Airpassengers(timestamp): 
    input=np.int(timestamp)
    prediction = model.predict(input)
    print(Prediction)
    return Prediction


def main():
    st.title("Air Passengers Predictor")
    st.header('Enter the timestamp:')
    timestamp = st.number_input('timestamp:', min_value=1, max_value=1000, value=1)
    output=""
    if st.button("Predict Passengers"):
        output = predict_Airpassengers(timestamp)
        st.success('The output is ;'.format(output))
if __name__=='__main__':
     main()
```

I want to deploy my model using streamlit but I keep getting this error, kindly help;

```py
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ScriptRunner.scriptThread'.
Traceback:
File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 563, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 844, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 582, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 439, in init_kernel
    shell_stream = ZMQStream(self.shell_socket)
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.io_loop = io_loop or IOLoop.current()
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 116, in current
    loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 263, in current
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
```

here is my github link; https://github.com/BenedictOdhiambo/GRU-Deployment

Comment: Does your program work without streamlit?

Comment: No it does not, would appreciate any help, its a gru